# Radio inside TD, unable to set width - all TD elements equal width and ignoring width style

Tags: css, html

I have a table that has a radio button in on `td` element, however i am unable to set the width (my page is in HTML5 so using the style css attribute to set the width).

My row is as follows:

```
<h3><span data-bind="text: description"></span></h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Description</th>
            <th>Setup</th>
            <th>Monthly</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: options -->
            <tr>
                <td style="width:16px"><input type="radio" data-bind=" attr: { name: $parent.name }, checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selection" /></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: description"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: setup == 0 ? '-' : setup"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: price == 0 ? '-' : price"></span></td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In fact all of the rows are 154px wide, each row is equal.

Don't worry about the data-bind attributes, i am using knockoutjs. I am using bootstrap for the stlying, but cant see any column widths applied fron the bootstrap CSS.

I have take a screenshot of chrome below:

[image: width is 154px for all td elements]

**Edit and further info**

After looking at the fiddle from @daker's comment here http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/Lnvny/, i could see the width was applied OK.

When going over my code, i have a thead section which is causing the issue, this is not present in the above fiddle.

Adding the below `thead` section to the fiddle stops the widths from applying on the `td` element, [updated here http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/Lnvny/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/Lnvny/2/)

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Description</th>
        <th>Setup</th>
        <th>Monthly</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

If i set the width in the th element with `<th colspan="2"  style="width:20px">Description</th>` it sizes, so the td elements are following the width of the td, which makes sense.

However the description spans across 2 columns with `colspan="2"` which consists of both the first `td` with radio, and second `td` with the text description data-bind in the tbody.

**Is there any way to keep the th colspan=2 in the thead, yet set the width of the radio button td=16px in tbody?**

Comment: You want to set the with to the `<td>` or to the radio?

Comment: Explain what doesn't work with this please: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvny/

Comment: True yours works... mine doesn't.  Same code. Must be a problem in css somewhere let me dig in and take a even closer look

Comment: @daker thanks for the reply - it is to do with the `thead` section which i have updated on your fiddle, edits posted on my original question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set width for second column as auto:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvny/46/

```
<h3><span data-bind="text: description"></span></h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Description</th>
            <th>Setup</th>
            <th>Monthly</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: options -->
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 15px;"><input type="radio" data-bind=" attr: { name: $parent.name }, checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selection" /></td>
                <td style="width: auto;">text<span data-bind="text: description"></span></td>
                <td style="width: 25%;"><span data-bind="text: setup == 0 ? '-' : setup"></span></td>
                <td style="width: 25%;"><span data-bind="text: price == 0 ? '-' : price"></span></td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

16px+40%+25%+25% is not 100%.
You can't mix px and % this way, the table rendering algorithm can't satisfy such conditions...

As mali303 said, you could set the second td to auto, or even simpler: Don't set its width. The last two colums will be 25% width, the first 16px width and all the remaining space will go for the second column (and 1st td + 2nd td will be 50%)

You could also go the simpler way:

Use 3 columns (50%,25%,25%), remove th colspan, and join the content of your 2 first columns
(both are inline elements):

```
<td style="width: 50%;">
 <input type="radio" data-bind="..." />
 <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<td style="width:1px"><div style="width:16px"><input type="radio" data-bind=" attr: { name: $parent.name }, checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selection" /></div></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty `<th></th>` in your `<thead>` section:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvny/48/

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Description</th>
        <th>Setup</th>
        <th>Monthly</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```